# React: trigger onChange if input value is changing by state with data coming from fetch?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, bootstrap-4

I am trying to fetch data from API after that i stored that data in API and it is working but i want one input box (in that input box after pasting website URL and then after clicking on that button i want to load those results in return div UI and i am not getting how can i set that onchange() e.target value to that data that is coming from API response below is my code

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import {Row, Col, Container, Button, Form, FormControl, Nav} from 'react-bootstrap'
export default function Home() {
const [State, setState] = useState("");

useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://lighthouse-dot-webdotdevsite.appspot.com//lh/newaudit", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({
      "url": "https://piyushsthr.netlify.app",
      "replace": true,
      "save": false
    }),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
      },
      credentials: "same-origin"
    })
     .then(res => res.json()) // this is the line you need
     .then(function(data) {
  
      setState(data.lhrSlim[0].score);

    }).catch(function(error) {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-expressions
      error.message
    })
  }, )
  return (
    <div>
       <Container >
        <h1>Enter Your website URL</h1>
        <Form >{/* onSubmit={} */}
            <FormControl type="text" placeholder="Search" className="mr-sm-2" name="query"/>
            <Button type="submit">Search</Button>
          </Form>
      </Container>
      <h1>{State}</h1>
    </div>
  )
}
```

can anyone help me with this thing and also suggest me some tips/resources on how can i improve my this kind of coding skills.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make something like this:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import { Container, Button, Form, FormControl } from "react-bootstrap";
export default function Home() {
  const [State, setState] = useState("");
  const ref = useRef(0); // add a ref to remove value from input when fetch is finish
  const [userUrl, setUserUrl] = useState("");
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  //if you don't need to fetch data when component is mount you can remove all the useEffect
  useEffect(() => {
    onFetch("https://piyushsthr.netlify.app");
  }, []); //passing a empty array told useEffect to be play only at the component did mount state
  const onFetch = (url) => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    fetch("https://lighthouse-dot-webdotdevsite.appspot.com//lh/newaudit", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({
        url: url,
        replace: true,
        save: false
      }),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
      },
      credentials: "same-origin"
    })
      .then((res) => res.json()) // this is the line you need
      .then(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        setState(data.lhrSlim[0].score);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-expressions
        error.message;
      })
      .finally((_) => {
        setIsLoading(false);
        ref.current.value = "";
      });
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <Container>
        <h1>
          Enter Your website URL
          <span role="img" aria-label="ufo">
            
          </span>
        </h1>
        <Form
          onSubmit={() => {
            onFetch(userUrl);
          }}
        >
          <FormControl
            ref={ref}
            type="text"
            placeholder="Search"
            className="mr-sm-2"
            name="query"
            onChange={(e) => {
              setUserUrl(e.target.value);
            }}
          />
          <Button>
            Search
            <span role="img" aria-label="search-icon">
              
            </span>
          </Button>
        </Form>
      </Container>
      {isLoading ? <h2>Loading...</h2> : <h2>{State}</h2>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I removed the `type="submit"`from button props too to avoid your component to re-render.
[image: Edit musing-yonath-xwljt]

Answer (score 1):

Well for your first question. if you want to make your input value set to the result from the API request. you should just have to add the `value={State}`.

```
return (
    <div>
       <Container >
        <h1>Enter Your website URL</h1>
        <Form >{/* onSubmit={} */}
            <FormControl type="text" value={State} placeholder="Search" className="mr-sm-2" name="query"/>
            <Button type="submit">Search</Button>
          </Form>
      </Container>
      <h1>{State}</h1>
    </div>
  )
```

For resource recommendation please read Robinwieruch blogs and Books.

Comment: in that input box after pasting website URL i want to load those results

Comment: Ya i understand. so the state you want load is `State` right?